# Using Firebase Cloud Firestore with custom Authentication Security (without Firebase Authentication)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use `Cloud Firestore` (Firebase DB) without using `Firebase Authentication` service.

I want to authenticate user from my Java code with my own implementation and then allow access to the Firestore database to valid users.

Is it possible to use `Firebase Cloud Firestore` DB by implementing our own authentication mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex answered: you will need to use Firebase Authentication to be able to properly secure access to your database.

But you can use your own identity provider with Firebase Authentication. That way your own Java code can handle the sign in, and then mint a token for Firebase to use to identify that user, and to secure data access with. For more in this see the [documentation on custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).

Comment: Thanks Frank! this is what I was looking for! I hope this will work for me, much appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use Firebase Cloud Firestore DB by implementing our own authentication mechanism?

Yes it is possible but what is not possible, is that you cannot secure it. To secure a Cloud Firestore database you need to use [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started):

> To build user-based and role-based access systems that keep your users' data safe, you need to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) with Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

So you need to be authenticated in order to secure your database, otherwise other users/application can access your database.